# how to make touchend event trigger on Vue without touchstart?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have `mousedown` and `mouseup` events working well on desktop, and need to make similar work on mobile.
The working code on desktop is

```
    <rect :x="xPos" :y="yPos" width="75"
     class="arrowbox"
     @mousedown="mousedown"   @mouseup="mouseup"
    />
```

and after finding I got no reaction to `mousedown` on mobile (galaxy tab) I tried this:

```
    <rect :x="xPos" :y="yPos" width="75"
     class="arrowbox"
     @mousedown="mousedown" @touchstart="mousedown"
     @mouseup="mouseup" @touchend="mouseup"
    />
```

This gave the correct response for `touchstart`on the mobile, but **both** `mouseup` and `touchend` now fired so I had two touches where I wanted just one.
So then I tried removing the `touchend` handler. The mobile touchscreen now works as intended *if the touch is done quickly*. If I touch, hold for two seconds and then release, the `touchend` event doesn't appear to trigger. Is there a solution to this?

I have seen other similar posts but they relate to `touchmove` events, which I don't need.

Comment: You could bind them conditionally depending on touch being detected

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it's not a vue-related issue, it's just my inexperience of programming `touch`.
I needed to add a different handler for the touch events, and call preventDefault() before using the same code as for the mouse events.

```
function touchstart(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  mousedown();
}
```